# Call to Javascript function from php

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am having difficulties when calling Javascript functions from inside php. First of all, I assume that is possible?! Secondly, how do you do it? Currently I have:

```
echo myFunction($name1);
```

inside the php and the function is declared as:

```
function myFunction(name)
```

but this gives:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function myFunction() in C:\xampp\htdocs\page.php on line 109
```

Please Help!

Comment: You *can't* call JavaScript functions in PHP.  PHP runs on your server.  It creates a page with HTML and JavaScript.  That page is downloaded by your browser where it is rendered.  That's where the JavaScript runs.  On the client.  I'm assuming `myFunction` is your JavaScript function.  So, you (probably) want the PHP to echo `myFunction` as string: `echo "myFunction({$name});";`.  You want the PHP to *generate* a JavaScript program.

Comment: Write the same function in php and then include it in your current php file

Comment: I suggest that before you do anything else, you learn what is running on the server side and client side, and when.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call a JavaScript function from PHP. PHP is a ***server side*** language while JavaScript is a ***client side*** language. The two know nothing about one another.

**EDIT:**

Depending on your requirements and the functions intent, you may be able to rewrite `myFunction` as a PHP function and then call it:

```
/* Create the function */
function myFunction($name) {
    ...
}

/* Call the function */
myFunction("name");
```

Comment: That depends what the function does.  Re-writing it in PHP might not achieve what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Very valid point. I shouldn't have made that assumption. I'll make a note of that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get php to output a self calling function like this

```
<?php
print "<script>(function (){
  //JavaScript stuff
})();”; ?>
```

That should execute the js when the browser hits it, you can use php variables inside this as they will be expanded by the server.  Your probably better off writing the functionality in a different way tho. Or if you really need server side php involved, to make an ajax call to that php script and grab some json